# Mass Flow Sensor missing

Tags: engine, volvo, air-intake, maf, v70

I've recently purchased a Volvo V70 I 2.4 (106kW, 1998, manual) and wanted to check the mass flow sensor for issues. But it appears that my car has none, even though I've seen them in all pictures and videos of V70s on the Internet so far.

Where other cars have the mass flow sensor, my car only has a temperature sensor (2 pin device) sitting between the air filter and throttle, and the pipe coming out of the air filter cover is longer than others.

Is it normal for a car to not have a mass flow sensor even though others with the same engine have one?

Comment: If you don't have a MAF sensor, the MAP sensor is doing its job. It may be possible that another car uses the same engine mechanical parts, but different control systems.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From what I'm seeing, you are right ... it should have a MAF sensor.

Comment: It seems like my car doesn't have a MAP sensor either, or I couldn't find it. So it's probably only controlled by the throttle valve potentiometer, revs of the engine and lambda sensor. Apparently that's good enough to infer an optimal mixture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal for this car not to have a mass flow sensor (MAF). The engine can be controlled with other parameters, including the throttle position and manifold air pressure, as well as the lambda sensor.

While many Volvo V70 and even some 850 have a MAF, the 2.4 engine also comes in a version without a MAF when you still have the mechanical throttle with a pulley system directly connected to the accelerator.